# How to handle dynamic json content in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON input with varying properties
Example 1 -

```
{
  "test1": {
       "A" : {
              Value : "1"
             },
      "B" : {
              Value : "2"
             }

           }
}

Example 2 - 
{
  "test2": {
       "C" : {
              Value : "3"
             }
}
```

I need to store these in SQL database in Name and Value columns as
Name Value
A     1
B     2
C     3`

The JSON could have different type of parent attributes like test1/Test2/test3. And, I need to store these in name value pairs. How do I achieve this in logic app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have designed a logic app workflow for you:

[image]

You can use [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) to convert Json by JavaScript. If your json format is the same as you gave, you can use the sample code I gave below:

```
var json = {  "test1" : {
       "A" : {
              "Value" : "1"
             },
      "B" : {
              "Value" : "2"
             }
  }
};

var value1 = Object.values(json)[0];

var array = [];

var key2 = Object.keys(value1);

var value2 = Object.values(value1);

for(var i = 0; i < key2.length; i++){
    array.push(key2[i]);
    array.push(Object.values(value2[i])[0]);
}

return array;
```

The result is like this:

[image]

**Note**

`Inline code` needs [integration accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account), you can refer to the official document I gave you.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort on this!! I implemented it using OpenJson and stored proc. And, executed the stored proecude via logic app.

Comment: Since, I needed to save the data in SQL table - I sent this json as input parameter to stored proc and wrote below query to insert the data in required table into name/value columns - INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT Attribute.[key] as [Name], AttributeValue.[value] as [Value]
  FROM OPENJSON(@Json) input
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(input.value) a
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value) b
  WHERE b.[key] = 'Value

Comment: Oops, looks like the code indentation doesnt work here. Hope, it still helps!